# iOS Could not share video to Whatsapp using UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: ios, video, whatsapp

It successfully redirects to the Whatsapp app.There is no preview frame and when tapped Send, an error messages pops up "This video could not be sent. Please choose a different video.

Here is my code.

```
- (void)shareVideo {
NSLog(@"[WhatsAppShare] sharing video");
//NSString *nativePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithCString:path encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *nativePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video" ofType:@"mp4"];

// Save video to path in documents directory
NSString *savePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/whatsAppTmp.wam"];

if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:savePath]){
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:savePath error:nil]){
        [self shareVideoAtNativePath:nativePath SavePath:savePath];
    }
} else {
    [self shareVideoAtNativePath:nativePath SavePath:savePath];
}}

- (void)shareVideoAtNativePath:(NSString*)nativePath SavePath:(NSString*)savePath{
NSError*error;
BOOL isSuccess=[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:nativePath toPath:savePath error:&error];
if(isSuccess){
    // Create interaction controller
    self.documentInteractionController          = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:savePath]];
    self.documentInteractionController.UTI      = @"net.whatsapp.movie";
    self.documentInteractionController.delegate = self;

    [self.documentInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)
                                                           inView:[self view]
                                                         animated:YES];
} else{
    NSLog(@"error %@", error);
}
}
```

Comment: While ali's answer is correct (`.wam` sharing is broken in the latest version of WhatsApp) you can share the video as `.m4v` and it will work OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have observed the exact same problem. Everything was working until a recent update of WhatsApp. This is probably a bug on WhatsApp side.

Here is a workaround for this problem:

- Do not use a wam file, use the mp4 file directly. So in your case, just call

  ```
  [self shareVideoAtNativePath:nativePath SavePath:nativePath];
  ```
- Change the UTI to public Mpeg4:

  ```
  self.documentInteractionController.UTI = @"public.mpeg-4";
  ```

This seems to have solved our issue. However, there is a drawback that, the share dialog now contains many other apps/services that can open mp4 files.

Comment: It doesn't work if Whatsapp isn't installed in phone?

Answer (score 1):

We've faced the exact same issue.

The official `.wam` format brings up only WhatsApp in the share dialog, but fails to forward the video.

Using `.m4v` format is working for us. A few more options are displayed along with WhatsApp (`Open in WhatsApp` is the option we want). We are displaying an alert saying "Please select Whatsapp on the next screen" before sending user to the share dialog.

**File format: `m4v`**

**UTI: `net.whatsapp.movie`**

Please refer to the working code below:

```
 UIDocumentInteractionController *documentInteractionController;
    -----
    -----
 - (void)shareVideoViaWhatsApp:(NSURL*)url{    
        // Creating temp video to share specifically on whatsapp.   
        NSString *cachesFolder = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"video.m4v"]];
        NSURL *file = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:cachesFolder];
        [[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url] writeToURL:file options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:nil];

        documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL: file ];
        documentInteractionController.UTI = @"net.whatsapp.movie";

        documentInteractionController.delegate = self;
        [documentInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// In code Use share GIF and Video for WhatsApp....

  NSString    *savePath  = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/whatsAppTmp.wam"];
savePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Movie" ofType:@"m4v"];
_documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:_videourl];
_documentInteractionController.UTI = @"net.whatsapp.movie";
_documentInteractionController.delegate = (id)self;
[_documentInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0) inView:self.view animated: YES];
```